# Event like "DOMLastNodeRemoved" to prevent multiple executions of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, genexus

First of all: I know that there are some questions similar to this, but I could not found any alternative to it, but to ask.

Hello!

Is there any event like "DOMLastNodeRemoved" (or FirstNode, since u can't know for sure when it will be the last node removed) to prevent multiple executions of code?

Here's the deal, I'm using Genexus. The only way to make an event work in this weird SPA concept is using DOMNodeRemoved event.
But whenever you click a button, it will insert a lot of nodes, making the function execute like 25 times instead of just one.

Let's go to an example:

I'm currently with this code:

```
$(document).on("DOMNodeRemoved", function() {
$(".Button").click(function() {
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            toastrgx();
            $('.gx-warning-message').css('display', 'none');
        }, 800);
});
function toastrgx() {

    var meuLoader = new Loader($);
    meuLoader.Insert();

    setTimeout(function() {
        meuLoader.Remove();
        var text = $('.gx-warning-message').text();
        toastr.error(text, '');

    }, 500);

    };
});
```

I need to use timeout because the DOM is still loading up the message.

Anyways, with this code I'll get this result presented in the image:

[image]

If i use something like preventPropagation (at least the way I used) it will run my code only once, but returns a lot of errors in the console (one for each execution) and also breaks my loader.
BTW, I have power only over one custom script, everything else is generated by Genexus.
So, if I use any other normal event like document.ready, it will fire the first time I load a page within my MasterPage, but, if I click in any other page, it will not fire the event again.

So, my question is:

**There is any way to execute a code only once in my case?**
Is it something that I'm not seeing clearly like another event or another way to make the code work?

If the question sounds silly, sorry, i'm a newbie in JS.

Comment: Your question is really not clear because you're asking about an attempted solution instead of telling us about the problem you want to solve. From the look of what you're trying to do there's probably a much better way, but it depends on the context you're working under.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry if I didn't make myself clear.
My problem is that I need to execute the function toastrgx(); only once instead of multiple times, which is leading to show the message a lot of times in the screen, like you can see in the screenshot. If I use the "common document.on.ready() solution", it will not work because of the way the framework is structured.

Comment: @Kaddath there are like max of 2 button class in each page, one to confirm and other to close the form. It isn't that is "necessary", but it is the only event that I find it working under the framework structure. I'm open to suggestions, perhaps I didn't think of an event that could solve my problem? So, to summarize, they aren't necessary, but its the only thing that keeps my code running instead of losing context like I do if I click in another page inside the same aplication.

Comment: I'd be happy to help (GeneXus developer here), but I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. Tell me about the underlying problem you want to solve.

Comment: @ncardeli I'm trying to find any event in JS to execute my functions everytime I change my view, i.e. going from Home to  any other page.  I'm currently importing my js file in my masterpage inside the Start event.
If I use any other event besides DOMNodeRemoved, my code will only trigger the first page I enter. If I do enter another page inside my application, my js function will not fire. The problem with DOMNodeRemoved is that he will execute my code multiple times, in every node he removes, and Genexus does this a lot of times. So, there is any other way to achieve what I want? Thx btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go in this case is creating a [User Control](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?5273,Category%3AUser%20Controls) and using its `show` function, that is executed by the generated application every time the control should update (for example, when the page is loaded or when a property of the control is modified).

### Why a User Control?

User Controls offer a standard interface to interoperate with GeneXus generated applications. This interface is well [documented](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?26973,User%20control%20structure%20overview,) and abstracts you from the inner workings of the generated applications.

If you try to extend GeneXus by including scripts, you will be exposed to unexpected behavior and changes without previous notice.

### How to create a User Control

To create a User Control I recommend using the [GeneXus User Control Generator](https://atom.io/packages/genexus-usercontrol-generator), for Atom. Using this Atom package you can easily create a GeneXus User Control.

Follow the [steps to create a User Control](https://github.com/genexuslabs/usercontrol-generator#using) and choose `Web` when prompted for the supported platforms by the package.

### How to have code execute only once, when the page is loaded

After creating the User Control, open the `src/<YourUserControlName>Render.js` file and edit the `show` function this way:

```
this.show = function() {
  if (!this.IsPostBack) {
    // This code will be executed only, when the page is loaded.
  }
}
```

Inside the `if` you can code whatever you need to execute only once per page.

### How to deploy a User Control

To build and deploy the User Control to your GeneXus installation directory, follow the [build process steps](https://github.com/genexuslabs/usercontrol-generator#build-process) described in the package documentation.

Once you have deployed your User Control, you should include it in the master page object, to start using it, instead of the script you are using now.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But just to be clear, there is no way around genexus without an UC?
It feels like creating a whole new tool to crack a coconut when I could just use a rock.

Comment: There are alternatives, but none would be robust enough to ensure future compatibility, as the one I proposed in my answer.

Comment: Hi, I made the UC, but I'm facing the same problem, I copied only my function and put a document on ready on it and put the UC on my masterpage. He only chooses to execute the function when she reloads it, not on every form load. 
Any other event that I could try?

Comment: You don't need to subscribe to the document ready event. The show function will be called when the document is ready and every time a new page is loaded.

Comment: Yes, yes, but the problem is that Genexus won't "refresh' the page with the masterpage concept. Whenever I click on another page, it will just load the webpage without making any refresh on it.